# Change Extjs Grid Validation Text

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm looking at an older project that is using ExtJS. Admittedly, I'm not too familiar with this framework so I learn as I go and as I am asked to fix things. My issue is that there is a grid and each column uses `allowBlank: false`. This causes a tooltip box to display with some info about what field(s) need to be populated. This all works great, but I am trying to change that text in that tooltip i.e. "Error", "Benefit Category Name: This field is required", and I can't seem to make this work. How can I target and change that text? I'll include a screenshot of the grid and tooptip that I am talking about for reference. I am also using ExtJS version 6.

Here is a sample of one of the grid columns:

```
columns: [
    {
        dataIndex: 'benefit_category_name',
        text: 'Benefit Category Name',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combo',
            store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                fields: [
                    'benefit_category_id',
                    'benefit_category_name',
                ],
                data: [],
            }),
            queryMode: 'local',
            valueField: 'benefit_category_name',
            displayField: 'benefit_category_name',
            emptyText: 'Select one',
            listeners: {
                select: 'handleComboChange',
            },
            itemId: 'benefit_category_id',
            allowBlank: false,
            listeners: {
                renderer: function(value, metaData) {
                    metaData.tdAttr = Ext.String.format('data-qtip="{0}"', value);
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

I tried to use the `metaData` property I read about in some other posts, but I can't seem to change the tooptip text (Error, Benefit Category Name: This field is required).

Here is a screenshot of the tooltip mentioned. I know this is an older framework, but any tips I could get would be useful. Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: Which toolkit is used: modern or classic. And what is the version?

Comment: Ok, it is classic toolkit, version >6.0.. It is wrong code, have a look at the grid`s 'Ext.grid.plugin.RowEdititng'.. in must be in the 'plugins' property of the grid. If you will not find there the tooltip, then look in the controller of grid. The tooltip you have presented appears in combobox editor of "Benefit Category Name".

Comment: @ArthurRubens Hi Arthur. Big thanks for the response. I did find `me.rowEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing({ clicksToEdit: 2, autoCancel: false });` in a view file. So I'm going to try to put some code in there and see what happens. Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: This depends, you can either use CellEditing or RowEditing. Your pic looks like, thats nothing wrong with that. More here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing.html 

To customize the text, try to use allowBlank in conjunction with vtype and vtypeText to customize the validation text. 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-vtypeText

Comment: @devbnz Thanks also for your response. I'll be looking into that as well. You wouldn't happen to have an on hand examples of how to use `allowBlank` with `vtype` and `vtypeText` would you? Either way, thank you for the tip.

Comment: i have added a simple example with a textfield, you can simply apply this to your combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a simple validation example with custom message.

```
Ext.create({
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank:false, // will show required message - remove key to display vtypeText only
            validateBlank: true,
            vtype: 'alpha', // check for available types or create / extend one
            vtypeText: 'Please change to what you want ...',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
```

Details:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.VTypes.html

https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3770